# Сбор и хранение данных из апи бирж

Tags: структуры-данных, хранение-данных

Надо снимать данные с апи десятка бирж, которые обновляются с регулярностью в 1 секунду, пытаюсь придумать как это правильно сделать.. пока только такой вариант:

1. php класс мультикурл с вызовом каждую 1 минуту и получением данных со всех бирж за последнюю минуту
2. сохранение полученного в mysql одна строка - одна секунда - с даными об одной бирже

Проблема:
Обновления слишком редкие (1 мин), но планировщик CRON не позволяет сделать 1 или 5 сек, только минуту..
Хранение в mysql настораживает.. через месяц база будет гигов 10 и как с ней потом работать... может надо в файлах хранить?

Подскажите, как вообще решают такие вопросы? Опыта ноль в организации подобной структуры, а сделать сервис который всё время падает или люто тупит не хотелось бы..

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: > через месяц база будет гигов 10 и как с ней потом работать... может надо в файлах хранить?

1. База и так хранится в файлах.
2. Создавайте при запуске сервера временную таблицу в памяти, пихайте туда данные за последние десять минут, старые удаляйте. Все остальное храните как хотите? там вряд ли ежеминутное разрешение понадобится. Опять же, по крону лишнее можно вычищать.

> Обновления слишком редкие

while (время < 50c):
sleep(10 сек)
выполнить запросы

Comment: спасибо камрад, можешь подскажешь специализированный класс для организации подобного?